# C#: How do you programmatically scale the Pricing Tier for an existing DocumentDB collection?

Tags: c#, azure, scalability, azure-cosmosdb

I'd like to be able to modify the OfferType (e.g. Pricing Tier `S2`, `S3`, etc.) of an existing DocumentDB collection from within C#, but I don't see any members of the `Microsoft.Azure.Documents.DocumentCollection` class that will facilitate this.

Is there another approach that would provide this functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see this code snippet for how to change the performance level of DocumentDB collections using the .NET SDK

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/documentdb-performance-levels/#changing-performance-levels-using-the-net-sdk

```
// Query the "offers" feed to retrieve the offer for the collection
Offer offer = client.CreateOfferQuery()
                    .Where(r => r.ResourceLink == "collection selfLink")    
                    .AsEnumerable()
                    .SingleOrDefault();

//Change the offer type to S1, S2 or S3
offer.OfferType = "S3";

//Now update the "offer" resource
Offer updated = await client.ReplaceOfferAsync(offer);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an updated example for the V2 offer type providing control over the DTU and the new per minute RU flag:

```
var collectionLink = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("databaseId","collectionName");
var response = await Client.ReadDocumentCollectionAsync(collectionLink);
var collection = response.Resource;

var results = await Client.CreateOfferQuery()
            .Where(o => o.ResourceLink == collection.SelfLink)
            .AsDocumentQuery()
            .ExecuteNextAsync<OfferV2>();

var offer = results.FirstOrDefault();

var updatedOffer = new OfferV2(offer, offerThroughput:800, offerEnableRUPerMinuteThroughput:true);

await Client.ReplaceOfferAsync(updatedOffer);
```

See also:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.azure.documents.offerv2.aspx